# What is the meaning of '_ in print()' in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch

Hi I just started learning Swift. I am just beginner to learn ios development.

```
func showOkay() {
    let title = NSLocalizedString("a title", comment: "")
    let message = NSLocalizedString("msg", comment: "")
    let cansal = NSLocalizedString("cancel", comment: "")
    let ok = NSLocalizedString("ok", comment: "")
    let alertController = UIAlertController (title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

    let cancelAlertAction = UIAlertAction (title : cansal, style : .cancel) {
        _ in print("cancel") // i don't understand this line . its just a print or somthing else. why i cant use print here.
    }
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: ok , style : .default) {
        _ in print("ok") // i don't understand this line. its just a print or somthing else. why i cant use print here.
    }

    alertController.addAction(cancelAlertAction)
    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: Any) {
     showOkay()
}
```

If I use `print()` only they give me errror like

> Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to expected argument type '((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement is using *trailing closure syntax*.  The stuff between `{` and `}` is actually a closure that is passed to `UIAlertAction` to be called later when the event happens.  When the closure is called, it will be passed the `UIAlertAction` object that was created.

```
let cancelAlertAction = UIAlertAction (title : cansal , style : .cancel) {
    _ in print("cancel") \\ i don't understand this line . its just a print or somthing else . why i cant use print here.
}
```

If you intend not to use the alert action, then you need the `_ in` to tell Swift that you are ignoring the `UIAlertAction` and doing nothing with it.  You are saying, I know there is a parameter but I am ignoring it.

If you don't specify the `_ in`, Swift infers your closure type to be of type `() -> ()` which means it takes nothing and produces nothing.  This doesn't match the type of the closure you are expected to provide which is `(UIAlertAction) -> Void` (takes a `UIAlertAction` and returns nothing).

It is usually written like this:

```
let cancelAlertAction = UIAlertAction (title : cansal , style : .cancel) { _ in
    print("cancel")
}
```

which makes it clearer that the `_ in` is the closure parameter syntax and not directly related to the `print` statement.